# Show a PlotShape when EMA20 CrossUnder EMA50

Tags: pine-script

I want to plot a shape when Close is Below EMA200 and EMA 20 CrossUnder EMA50.

This is my code:

```
//@version=4
study("1H Strategy", overlay=true)

myEMA20 = ema(close, 20)
myEMA50 = ema(close, 50)
myEMA200 = ema(close, 200)

isShort = false

if close < myEMA200 and crossunder(myEMA20, myEMA50)
    isShort := true

plotshape(isShort, style=shape.triangledown)
```

It looks good to me but it doesn't plot the shape.

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiELW.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had only click to Add to Chart.

Problem solved.